# Как извлечь строку запуска из .lnk (ярлык Windows)?

Tags: linux

Имеется файл .lnk, в котором содержится довольно сложная строка запуска приложения. Соответственно, Linux с ним не работает.  Строку не помню, как ее составлять - тоже не помню. В hex-редакторе, в просмотре mc - двоичная каша. Как извлечь из него эту строку?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделать это можно с помощью [`lnkinfo`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/liblnk-utils/lnkinfo.1.en.html).

Установить `liblnk-utils` для debian-подобной системы можно с помощью команды:

```sh
sudo apt install liblnk-utils
```

Теперь можно посмотреть содержимое `file.lnk` файла следующей командой:

```sh
lnkinfo file.lnk
```

На выходе этой команды будет много разных данных, вытащить нужный параметр `Local path` можно с помощью `grep` и `sed`:

```sh
lnkinfo file.lnk |
  grep "Local path" |
  sed 's/^[[:blank:][:alpha:]]*:[[:blank:]]*//'
```

Файлы LNK имеют бинарный формат, но спецификация этого формата открыта, документация есть на [на сайте Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-shllink).